# What is the fastest way to search for substring in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, algorithm, substring

I want to understand the performance issues that can emerge while making substring search in Java. I know the two built-in methods of searching for substring in Java.

**1. String.indexOf()**

As far as I understand this method uses the brute-force algorithm of substring search, thus its complexity is O(nm) where n and m are lengths of string and pattern.

**2. Use Pattern and Matcher**

I know nothing about how the regex algorithms are implemented and about their complexity.

*So the questions are:*

1) Which of these methods is preferrable from the perspective of performance?

2) What is the complexity of regex search? Does it depends on the regex itself?

Comment: [Aho-Corasick](https://github.com/raymanrt/aho-corasick) is the best choice, if you're really concerned about speed

Comment: [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm), with optimizations, is proven to be in linear time in the worst case scenario.  Of course, that kind of...defeats the purpose of the question in terms of what is presented.  Do you want the fastest way to search for a substring given only those tools?  What kinds of substrings are you looking for?  Could you provide examples of input and expected output?

Comment: The complexity of a regex search varies greatly depending on what's being matched. Most of the times it matches very quickly __but because of backtracking__ there incurs a lot of time in a fail match.

Comment: I would choose _indexOf()_ over a regex when possible.

Comment: The reason `indexOf` uses that algorithm is because it's the fastest in practice in most cases, even if other algorithms might have better asymptotics in theory.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ Patterns are essentially a generalized Aho-Corasick (which is a generalized KMP). Because they all build up something like a state machine, I tend to favor Rabin–Karp if I'm just doing the match once.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ: Jesus, no.  Aho-Corasick builds a failure function for a set of strings.  That requires linear space, and the text-matching phase gets to look at the failure function whenever there's a failure.  This means a considerable constant factor overhead above what a constant-space method would take.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: Look at the code.  Java doesn't turn regexes into DFAs or any such thing.  It turns them into a tree of these `Node` objects that implement a naive regex matcher.  There's a special hack in there---use Boyer-Moore if you're trying to match a string instead of doing it naively, character-by-character.

Comment: @tmyklebu So it does build up a DFA, but it handles alternation naively rather than by building a NFA, then doing powerset construction. At least the Oracle version. Not sure about Classpath.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: It's not a DFA at all.  It's a graph of objects that call other objects recursively.  Don't use it *unless* you're trying to get at the Boyer-Moore inside.

Comment: @tmyklebu It's deterministic and has states. I wouldn't split hairs over the evaluation happening in the nodes rather than outside them.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: Dude, it's not a DFA.  A DFA state looks at the next character, transitions to another state, and completely forgets about everything that just happened.  This is a backtracking implementation.

Comment: @Unihedron: No backtracking for Java regexes when they're just doing string matching.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: People say that a lot.  You want naive string matching when the needle is *short*.  You want two-way matching when the needle is *long*.  Most uses of string matching in the wild are of the "find `://` in a URL" variety, where, owing to the short needle, you very much do want the naive method.  People have gotten used to writing their own string matchers when they have to do something nontrivial *precisely because* library implementations are often bunk.  That's not a great reason to avoid improving the library.  (And the `if (len < thresh)` check really doesn't hurt.)`

Comment: @tmyklebu Fine, there's a meta state implied by the call stack. It's a different way of structuring the same thing that's more practical.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: No, it's a very, very, very different thing from a DFA.  Matching does not take linear time, for instance, even for the kinds of regular expressions they taught you about in school.  See the code in my answer.

Comment: Makoto, I just want to know which way is faster to search for an exact substring match: regex or brute-force or some algorithm like KMP or Boyer-Moore implemented well? I suppose No1 is some algorithm, ok, which is No 2 option if I dont want to code anything by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, if you care about worst-case performance, JNI into native code that calls your standard library's `strstr` function.  Well-implemented `strstr`, like the one in recent versions of glibc, has linear worst-case running time and constant worst-case space usage.  I believe glibc's `strstr` can do Boyer-Moore-like long jumps through the text, too.  C standard libraries are maintained by people who know how to write and maintain good and general-purpose libraries and practise their craft.  The same cannot be said for the Java standard class library.

You will have to turn a Java UTF-16 string into something suitable for `strstr`, such as a UTF-8 string.  You will also have to handle embedded zero bytes in the UTF-8 string gracefully.  Other than that, you will reap the benefits of a well-written and well-maintained library.

Java does regex searches (for this particular case) using a Boyer-Moore string search hacked into a naive regex implementation.  Compiling a `Pattern` with just your string will result in a `Matcher` that performs relatively well.  Note, however, that this does NOT extend to anything beyond string searching with the regex library; you're still stuck with a naive regex implementation that backtracks and all if you feed it a nontrivial regular expression.

As evidence for why you shouldn't use Java regex for actual regexes, I present you the following:

```
public class regex {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String haystack = "ab";
    String needle = "abab?.*";
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) haystack = haystack + haystack;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) needle = needle + needle;
    System.out.println(haystack.length() + " " + needle.length());
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(Pattern.matches(needle, haystack));
    long after = System.currentTimeMillis(); // long after indeed...
    System.out.println(after - before);
  }
}
```

This is a search in a 256-character haystack for a needle regex (that's an honest regex that you learnt about in compilers class) of 112 characters.  It takes about 24 seconds to complete on my machine.

Comment: @Unihedron: It really won't.  Go grab any intro compilers book and read up on how to implement regular expressions.  Or look at Russ Cox's regex implementation at http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/.

Comment: Know any better regex engines? Perl 5.10 takes 40% longer than Java 1.8.

Comment: @laune: Russ Cox's page has pointers to four implementations.  I've personally used Russ's re2 library.  You can verify that it works properly with the example I gave.

Comment: tmyklebu, I just cannot get from your answer - which way is faster to search for an exact substring match: regex or brute-force or some algorithm like KMP or Boyer-Moore implemented well?

Comment: I suppose No1 is some algorithm, ok, which is No 2 option if I dont want to code anything by myself?

Comment: If you use the Java regex engine for string matching, you get a Boyer-Moore string matcher.  This will usually be the faster of the two methods for a pattern of nontrivial length.  This appears to be the *only* thing the Java regex engine does well.