# does text contains substring

Tags: java, algorithm, pattern-matching, substring, string-matching

How to check if some String contains a specific String like "ABC72961". So we search for String which starts with "ABC" following by 5 digits. I've implemented a algorithm but I want it with "matches" or somehow else and then check the speed of these two solutions.

Comment: In the future make sure you tag your questions with the appropriate language.

Comment: I forgot it. Tack so micke :)

Comment: This sounds like a regex solution.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But how to write a regex for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to search for substring in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24602422/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-search-for-substring-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) for this

`^ABC[0-9]{5}$`

- `^` : Beginning of the string
- `ABC` : Matches ABC literally (case-sensitive)
- `[0-9]{5}` : Matches 5x numbers from 0 to 9
- `$` : End of the string

And use `String#matches` to test it

---

### [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uI9qG6/1)

---

### Example

```
String regex = "^ABC[0-9]{5}$";
String one = "ABC72961";
String two = "ABC2345";
String three = "AB12345";
String four = "ABABABAB";

System.out.println(one.matches(regex));      // true
System.out.println(two.matches(regex));      // false
System.out.println(three.matches(regex));    // false
System.out.println(four.matches(regex));     // false
```

---

### EDIT

Seeing your comment, you want it to work for `String one = "textABC72961text"` also. For that to be possible, you should just erase `^` and `$` that limit the String.

`.*ABC[0-9]{5}.*`

---

### EDIT 2

Here is if you want to extract it

```
if (s.matches(".*ABC[0-9]{5}.*")) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("ABC[0-9]{5}").matcher(s);
    m.find();
    result = m.group();
}
```

Comment: Yes, but your solution doesn't work for   **String one = "textABC72961text";**  and I need to return this string if it exists.

Comment: @myanmar If it should work for this, you need to excluse `^` and `$`

Comment: @myanmar Next time be sure about your specifiations and post them. It'll make it easy for everyone to find the correct answer;

Comment: You are absolutely right. But it doesn't work again. I got false as a result.

Comment: @myanmar [`[\\w]+ABC[0-9]{5}[\\w]+`](https://regex101.com/r/cB1jP8/1) You want to match the entire string I suppose? This will do.

Comment: Yes, it works now. Can I somehow return this string from a given text. I have String one = "textABC72961text" and I need to return "ABC72961" because it matches the pattern

Comment: @YassinHajaj Using `\\w` means that it only finds the substring if all other characters are word-characters but special character should be allowed too, and using `+` means there has to be such characters. Replace with `.*`, as in `matches(".*ABC[0-9]{5}.*")`.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)
 at test.Test.main(Test.java:15)

Comment: @myanmar This is strange, wait.

Comment: Yes, works like a charm. Thank you. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String indexOf command like this:

```
int result = someString.indexOf("ABC72961")
```

result will be -1 if there are no matches.

If there is a match, the result will be the index where the match starts.

Comment: Yes, but the string contains always wit "ABC" but the five digit number can be different. And I have to say if there is a string which starts with ABC following by 5 digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
str.contains("ABC72961");
```

Returns true if `str` contains the string. False if not.

Comment: Yes, but the string contains always wit "ABC" but the five digit number can be different. And I have to say if there is a string which starts with ABC following by 5 digits.

Comment: `str.contains("ABC");`

Comment: I have to return this String from a given text or find such string in a given text.

Comment: Ok, now you're just changing the desired outcome every time someone makes a suggestion.

Comment: No, it is not my attention to do this. Someone can correct my questions. For example, I have String one = "textABC72961text"  and I need to return "ABC72961" because it matches the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use is `java.util.regex.Pattern`.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ABC(\d*)"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher("ABC72961"); 
boolean b = m.matches();
```

or if it shall be exactly 5 digits after "ABC", you can use the regex `ABC(\d{5})`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String)

---

Another solution would be:

```
String stringToTest = "ABC72961"
boolean b = stringToTest.contains("ABC");
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_contains.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getString() {
        String str = extractString();
        return str;
    }

    public boolean exists() {
        return !getString().trim().equals("") ? false : true;
    }

    private List<Integer> getPositionsOfABC() {
        List<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<>();
        int index = text.indexOf("ABC");
        while (index > 0) {
            positions.add(index);
            index = text.indexOf("ABC", index + 1);
        }
        return positions;
    }

    private static boolean isInteger(String str) {
        boolean isValidInteger = false;
        try {
            Integer.parseInteger(str);
            isValidInteger = true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            return isValidInteger;
        }
        return isValidInteger;
    }

    private String extractString() {
        List<Integer> positions = getPositionsOfABC();
        for (Integer position : positions) {
            int index = position.intValue();
            String substring = text.substring(index, index + LENGTH_OF_DIGITS);
            String lastDigits = substring.substring(3, substring.length());
            if (isInteger(lastDigits)) {
                return substring;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple code that checks whether a substring exists in a string without using library functions, regex or other complex data structures.

```
class SSC {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String main_str <-- MAIN STRING
    String sub_str <-- SUBSTRING
    String w; int flag=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=main_str.length()-sub_str.length();i++){
        w="";
        for(int j=0;j<sub_str.length();j++){
            w+=main_str.charAt(i+j);
        }
        if(w.equals(sub_str))
        flag++;
    }
    if(flag>0)
    System.out.print("exists "+flag+" times");
    else
    System.out.print("doesn't exist");  
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.